# ie8 top navigation hidden

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I've added a top bar to my website for some links/icons and it works fine in all browsers except IE 8.  I have added conditional formatting just for this  but nothing has worked. Tried removing the black bar background, but still they wouldn't show.  You can hover over the space where they should be and click on the links, but visibly they just won't show.

[website](http://www.birdbathgroup.com/template.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this as a problem with CSS sprites only in IE<9.

Bad code:

```
#nav_garments{background:url(objectsConst.png)-678px 0px no-repeat;}
```

Good code:

```
#nav_garments{background:url(objectsConst.png) -678px 0px no-repeat;}
```

Notice the space after the parenthesis.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just noticed your website link and how my answer is unrelated.  In IE8 I just changed removed the .hidenav{display:none;} and set .container-navigation{display:none;} and it looks the same as chrome as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks all.  I have been banging my head on this one.  So I ended up hiding this style for my social_bookmarks class, then adding the {filer: none} to the IE8 css. 

/**filter: alpha(opacity=0.8);**/
 -moz-opacity:0.8;
 -khtml-opacity: 0.8; 
 opacity: 0.8;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease; 
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}